# Xamarin.Forms ios WebViewRenderer compartilhando Cookies

Tags: c#, cookies, webview, xamarin-forms, xamarin.ios

Estou utilizando um WebViewRenderer para configuração a política de cookies e também para compartilhar cookies de um request de login de um HTTPClient. Acontece que por mais que eu dê o set:
 `var cookieJar = NSHttpCookieStorage.SharedStorage;
   cookieJar.AcceptPolicy = NSHttpCookieAcceptPolicy.Always;`

Ao depurar o no simulador do iphone e executar o webview é indicado no browser que a política de cookies não está habilitado, sendo assim o usuário não consegue fazer o login pois o webview executa um iframe de um ambiente seguro. Abaixo está o código:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Foundation;
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Projeto.Custom;
using Projeto.iOS.Renderers;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;
using WebKit;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomWebView), typeof(CustomWebViewRenderer))]
namespace Mynamespace.iOS.Renderers
{
    public class CustomWebViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<CustomWebView, WKWebView>
    {

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<CustomWebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if(Control == null)
            {
                var userController = new WKUserContentController();
                var config = new WKWebViewConfiguration { 
                UserContentController = userController };
                var webView = new WKWebView(Frame, config);
                SetNativeControl(webView);
            }

            if(e.OldElement != null)
            {
                var hybrid = e.OldElement as CustomWebView;
                hybrid.Cleanup();
            }

            if(e.NewElement != null)
            {
                var baseUrl = new NSUrl(NSBundle.MainBundle.BundlePath, 
                true);
                string content = Element.Uri;
                Control.LoadHtmlString(content, baseUrl);              

                var cookieUrl = new 
                Uri("https://secure.gooddata.com/gdc/account/login");
                var cookieJar = NSHttpCookieStorage.SharedStorage;
                cookieJar.AcceptPolicy = NSHttpCookieAcceptPolicy.Always;
                foreach (var aCookie in cookieJar.Cookies)
                {
                    cookieJar.DeleteCookie(aCookie);
                }

                var jCookies = 
                CustomCookie.CookieContainer.GetCookies(cookieUrl);
                IList<NSHttpCookie> eCookies =
                    (from object jCookie in jCookies
                     where jCookie != null
                     select (Cookie)jCookie
                     into netCookie
                     select new NSHttpCookie(netCookie)).ToList();
                cookieJar.SetCookies(eCookies.ToArray(), cookieUrl, cookieUrl);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Se alguém puder me indicar qual é a melhor maneira de ativar a politica de cookies no WebView nativo do ios, agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bom depois de quebrar a cabeça, consegui resolver simplesmente troquei o  WKWebView por UIWebView. O que parece é que o WKWebView está com bug para acessar o NSHttpCookieStorage.SharedStorage, conforme essa discussão aqui [Veja](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/41039/setting-cookies-in-a-webview)

Portanto é só substituir no ViewRenderer o WKWebView por UIWebView e tudo funciona perfeitamente. Notei no desempenho também o UIWebView demonstra ser mais rápido, no meu caso estou carregando um HtmlString com um iframe incorporado com dezenas de gráficos e o UIWebView, demonstrou ser superior.